# Is there any condition for matched filter to be optimal?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convolution, signal-processing

The question is related to the optimallity of matched filter. The definition of matched filter is given in the link here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matched_filter

Cosider that the signal is corrupt with a single frequency sinusoid along with the desired signal. This means the noise defined in the wikipedia link is a single frequency sinusoid (frequency is known)and some noise. In such case

a) is the matched filter alone is optimal or

b) a combination of a band pass filter and matched filter? The band pass filter is used before the  matched filter to remove the unwanted sinusoid.

One can do simulation to find out some insight but can we proof something mathematically? In other words, the question: is the optimal condition is for added white noise only?
Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: The wiki link has the model x=s+v where s is the signal and v is the noise. The model I am talking about is x=s+v+one_sinusoid. The frequency of the sinusoid is known and is not in band with s.

Comment: If the sinusoid frequency is known, you can simply subtract the additive sinusoid from the received signal

Comment: @Stelios I assumed we need to know the exact phase also to remove it from time domain. We only know the frequency not the phase.

Comment: Even so, this is still a trivial case. Simply compute the Fourier transform of the received signal and declare the existence of the signal if there exist frequency components different than the sinusoidal frequency.

Comment: @Stelios How are we proving the optimality of a or b?

Comment: The way you stated your problem, there is no need to consider either options a or b. You are dealing with a degenerate case where there is no ambiguity in the detection problem and it doesn't even make sense to talk about "optimality" here. I am not even sure one can define a matched filter for this problem (what do you think it would be?)

Comment: The matched filte is the signal one transmits(reverse).The known transmitted signal, it may ne be sinusoid.I added the word noise in addition to the sinusoid to me it appropriate as per your suggestion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95306/discussion-between-stelios-and-creator).